# Where can I get a list of possibilities in migration classes?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

i

I am new to rails and ruby. I am trying to make a ActiveRecord::Migration to match my wishes, but where can I find documentation for what is possible in a ActiveRecord::Migration? I mean how to define field lengths for e.g. string and if null values are allowed or not and how to define/create different indexes?

Thank you
Søren

Comment: Neigaard, if one of the the answers was correct and helped you, you should mark it as the accepted answer by clicking on the check box outline to the left of the answer. You can also vote it up, if you want. More info on stackoverflow.com/faq on section 'How do I ask questions here?'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. [TableDefinitions#column](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/TableDefinition.html#M001525)s to see what options you can use on creating columns.
2. [SchemaStatements](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/SchemaStatements.html) for methods that can be used in migration.
3. [Migration on RoR Guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/migrations.html#creating-a-table).